# Can DreamWeaver _notes folders and dwsync.xml files be safely ignored by source control?

Tags: version-control, dreamweaver

I see Dreamweaver generated `_notes` folders (containing `dwsync.xml` files) being checked into our source control system by our newly acquired design team.

I've never used Dreamweaver but Google research tells me they have something to do with synchronising files between the local machine and a remote server.

I am guessing this is meta-data specific to their machine and serves no useful purpose for other team members on other machines?

Can I safely configure their source control client to ignore this folder when checking in files and folders?

Comment: I agree with you that these files shouldn't be added to version control.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to this [Adobe help article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405835.html):

> When you put or get a file in Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 and CS5, Dreamweaver locally stores the remote and local date/time stamps in files called `dwsync.xml`, which are located in hidden `_notes` folders in the same folder as the files being transferred.

Considering that, in case of corruption, Adobe's advice is to delete those files, close Dreamweaver, re-open it in order to re-generate said files, that means we are talking about *generated content*.

And generated content usually doesn't need to be versioned.